# How to get back a deleted project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, backup

Today, by mistake i deleted an entire android project from *Eclipse Helios*. I searched for it all over the web, i found that we have to open the project navigator and then click on 'Restore from local history'. But it didn't work.I didn't understand what to do. Is there any way how we can get a deleted project back in android. Please give me a step by step way to recover it. My hours of work is in vain. Please, Please help me.

Comment: At least you now know why you should be using version control (SVN, Git, etc.) - if you commit frequently you always have a backup (either locally in the .git folder or remote if you pushed it or use svn)

Answer (score 14):

If you have deleted the contents on disk and on eclipse there is still a small chance you can recover some of the project files.

If you search the eclipse Workspace metadata there are files stored in the history there. These files are named completely differently though but if you have an idea of the date of when you were working on it you may be able to recover some files for the project.

Directory tree is the same on both windows and linux
workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history

Comment: This echos the most recent revision to the screen for me fgrep -l UniqueTextInFileToSearchFor . -R | xargs ls -l | cut -f 8-13 -d ' ' | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs cat

Comment: This is awesome i found my permanently deleted code under workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history. This should be the accepted answer here. Thanks brother.

Comment: You saved my life! This works very well if you've totally deleted the entire project. I don't even know how I did it, but it was gone, but now it's back!

Comment: I found it a bit hard to find that folder. Look for the directory `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history` (at least under Windows). And many thanks to @Nanotron for this hint, it saved me some hours of tedious work ...

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes "Delete" just means "Do not show in Project Expplorer". You can choose the File >> Import >> Existing Projects into Workspace. Then there is a dialog Select Root directory your Eclipse workspace should be already selected...OK

There is a checkbox...Add project to working sets. Set this and choose the project you want to bring back.
Hey Presto.

It could happen that the package name is already in use. This causes many errors. The thing to do is to open the package to be discarded and refactor the package, renaming it to something harmless.

Now I'm back in business and Happy to share my success (so far)

By the way the backing up and management of files and workspaces is complex. I'm sure it is correct to a Linux Guru, but it is not intuitive. tread softly. If you do not choose "Copy Projects into Workspace", the files used for the compilation are left in  their original places on the disks. I feel this warning needs repeating.

Answer (score 7):

Just found an answer to this while trying to recover my own accidentally deleted package.

http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/1/18/How-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-Eclipse

In summary (in case the link goes bad) right click on the src package in project explorer and from the context menu, select the 'Restore from Local History...' button. It will bring up a list of file that can be restored.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked in your workspace folder? If it isnt there its hard to restore it. There is programs out there that can restore it, but i dont know a good one. Even if you find a good program, it might not be able to restore it.

I suggest you start making backups of your projects so this wont happen again.

Comment: +1. This is where I'd start - check whether the project is physically deleted from your workspace folder (and not just logically deleted from Eclipse). Then, start thinking about backups...

Comment: Yes, its there in the workplace. but how do i bring it back to eclipse. Thank you a lot. you saved me from the massacre of my career.

Comment: In eclipse press File -> Import. A dialog will popup and select Existing project into workspace. Select the workspace folder and check the project.

Answer (score 2):

go straight into your /workspace now!
look for it in your computer directory under the eclipse folder
or go to
file> import> existing project into workspace> (check: select archive file) and click browse it should still be there.
i found mine in there and backed it up. so happy :D

Answer (score 1):

Restore it from your backups...

Comment: Same way the rest of your machine is backed up

Answer (score 1):

if You checked delete from Local Disk then you press CTRL+Z your project is created,

and if you did not checked delete from local work space then you can import it.
form file menu> Import >>existing project from work space,and choose your path of project.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the guidelines below:

1. Go to: >File>Open Projects from File System...
2. Select your Import Source (look for your work-space).
3. Select the project you deleted from package explorer.
4. Click finish.

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted the project from eclipse only then it can be restores from above mentioned processes but if you deleted files from eclipse as well as directory then there is one option to restore the project files in eclipse:

1. Right click on project and then choose "Restore From Local History"
2. All deleted files will be come with check boxes. Chose the files which you want to restore and then restore.

Answer (score 0):

It accidentally got deleted when I was trying to export it to github, I found it in recycle bin and restored it in my workspace and then imported back to eclipse.